# Pie chart problem does not show if data is missing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP pie chart which uses data from Mysql to show the chart. However if one data is missing the whole chart turns to one color. For example for grading if the input is A, B, D and F(pay attention C grade input is missing) then the whole pie chart is in one color like Orange or red. 
Can you please help me with this? Thanks

```
<?php

$show_label = true; // true = show label, false = don't show label.
$show_percent = true; // true = show percentage, false = don't show percentage.
$show_text = true; // true = show text, false = don't show text.
$show_parts = false; // true = show parts, false = don't show parts.
$label_form = 'square'; // 'square' or 'round' label.
$width = 199;
$background_color = 'FFFFFF'; // background-color of the chart...
$text_color = '000000'; // text-color.
$colors = array('0000ff', '006600', 'ffff00','DD7C1D', 'FF3300', 'CC6600','990000','520000','BFBFC1','808080'); // colors of the slices.
$shadow_height = 16; // Height on shadown.
$shadow_dark = true; // true = darker shadow, false = lighter shadow...

// DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE...

$data = $_GET["data"];
$label = $_GET["label"];

$height = $width/2;
$data = array_filter(explode('*',$data));

if ($label != '') $label = explode('*',$label);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($label); $i++) 
{
    if ($data[$i]/array_sum($data) < 0.1) $number[$i] = ' '.number_format(($data[$i]/array_sum($data))*100,1,',','.').'%';
    else $number[$i] = number_format(($data[$i]/array_sum($data))*100,1,',','.').'%';
    if (strlen($label[$i]) > $text_length) $text_length = strlen($label[$i]);
}

if (is_array($label))
{
$antal_label = count($label);
$xtra = (5+15*$antal_label)-($height+ceil($shadow_height));
if ($xtra > 0) $xtra_height = (5+15*$antal_label)-($height+ceil($shadow_height));

$xtra_width = 5;
if ($show_label) $xtra_width += 20;
if ($show_percent) $xtra_width += 45;
if ($show_text) $xtra_width += $text_length*8;
if ($show_parts) $xtra_width += 35;
}

$img = ImageCreateTrueColor($width+$xtra_width, $height+ceil($shadow_height)+$xtra_height);

ImageFill($img, 0, 0, colorHex($img, $background_color));

foreach ($colors as $colorkode) 
{
    $fill_color[] = colorHex($img, $colorkode);
    $shadow_color[] = colorHexshadow($img, $colorkode, $shadow_dark);
}

$label_place = 5;

if (is_array($label))
{
for ($i = 0; $i < count($label); $i++) 
{
    if ($label_form == 'round' && $show_label)
    {
        imagefilledellipse($img,$width+11,$label_place+5,10,10,colorHex($img, $colors[$i % count($colors)]));
        imageellipse($img,$width+11,$label_place+5,10,10,colorHex($img, $text_color));
    }
    else if ($label_form == 'square' && $show_label)
    {   
        imagefilledrectangle($img,$width+6,$label_place,$width+16,$label_place+10,colorHex($img, $colors[$i % count($colors)]));
        imagerectangle($img,$width+6,$label_place,$width+16,$label_place+10,colorHex($img, $text_color));
    }

    if ($show_percent) $label_output = $number[$i].' ';
    if ($show_text) $label_output = $label_output.$label[$i].' ';
    if ($show_parts) $label_output = $label_output.$data[$i];

    imagestring($img,'2',$width+20,$label_place,$label_output,colorHex($img, $text_color));
    $label_output = '';

    $label_place = $label_place + 15;
}
}
$centerX = round($width/2);
$centerY = round($height/2);
$diameterX = $width-4;
$diameterY = $height-4;

$data_sum = array_sum($data);

$start = 270;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) 
{
    $value += $data[$i];
    $end = ceil(($value/$data_sum)*360) + 270;
    $slice[] = array($start, $end, $shadow_color[$value_counter % count($shadow_color)], $fill_color[$value_counter % count($fill_color)]);
    $start = $end;
    $value_counter++;
}

for ($i=$centerY+$shadow_height; $i>$centerY; $i--) 
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($slice); $j++)
    {
        ImageFilledArc($img, $centerX, $i, $diameterX, $diameterY, $slice[$j][0], $slice[$j][1], $slice[$j][2], IMG_ARC_PIE);
    }
}   

for ($j = 0; $j < count($slice); $j++)
{
    ImageFilledArc($img, $centerX, $centerY, $diameterX, $diameterY, $slice[$j][0], $slice[$j][1], $slice[$j][3], IMG_ARC_PIE);
}

OutputImage($img);
ImageDestroy($img);


function colorHex($img, $HexColorString) 
{
        $R = hexdec(substr($HexColorString, 0, 2));
        $G = hexdec(substr($HexColorString, 2, 2));
        $B = hexdec(substr($HexColorString, 4, 2));
        return ImageColorAllocate($img, $R, $G, $B);
}

function colorHexshadow($img, $HexColorString, $mork) 
{
    $R = hexdec(substr($HexColorString, 0, 2));
    $G = hexdec(substr($HexColorString, 2, 2));
    $B = hexdec(substr($HexColorString, 4, 2));

    if ($mork)
    {
        ($R > 99) ? $R -= 100 : $R = 0;
        ($G > 99) ? $G -= 100 : $G = 0;
        ($B > 99) ? $B -= 100 : $B = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ($R < 220) ? $R += 35 : $R = 255;
        ($G < 220) ? $G += 35 : $G = 255;
        ($B < 220) ? $B += 35 : $B = 255;               
    }           

    return ImageColorAllocate($img, $R, $G, $B);
}

function OutputImage($img) 
{
    header('Content-type: image/jpg');
    ImageJPEG($img,NULL,100);
}

?>
```

Comment: who is data and label ?

Comment: I tested $label = "test 1 * test 2 * test 3";
$data = "10 * 20  * 30";

Comment: the pizza is ok with all colors

Comment: after $data = array_filter(explode('*',$data)); you should compare if (count($data)==count($label)) and show the results only if both has the same value because the graph only makes sense if both arrays have the same dimention

Comment: if one value of data is zero, the graph misrepresent the colors

Comment: but the percentages are still correct

Comment: for example: $label = "test 1 * test 2 * test 3";
$data = "10 * 0  * 10";

Comment: Missing and zero are two different things

Comment: This is exactly the problem. Some students get between 90 to 100(A students) and some between 70 to 79.99(C students) and 60 to 69.99(D students) and 0 to 59.99(F students) as you see if none of students get a score between 80 to 89.99 then the whole chart shows only red or yellow or green. I have set the colors as: Blue is A and Green is B, Orange is C and yellow is D and F is red. 
It does not show let's say 4 students got A and others got C and D and F. It should be missing the green color and the rest should be correct colors with the percentages.